# How to get updated dropdownlist value from gridview row on save?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I am having an issue with a dropdownlist inside of a gridview.

The gridview is update on the rowcreated command with a dropdownlist and a set of values (which works fine). The selected values in the dropdownlist can be changed by the user and then saved.

When I click save, I need to get each new selected value from the dropdownlist and store it in an int list if it hasnt already been added.

This all works OK but I can't get the updated value that the user selected, only what was already populated as the selected item when it was setup.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    foreach (GridViewRow r in gvOrder.Rows)
    {
        if (r.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = r.FindControl("ddlNewO") as DropDownList;
            int value = Convert.ToInt16(ddl.SelectedItem.Text);
            bool Contains = list.Contains(value);
            if (!Contains)
            {
                list.Add(value);
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "This value is already assigned!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example: if there are 9 rows, each dropdown has numbers 1-9 and it's selected number is the row index. If I go in after page load and select the first three as '1' and click save, it runs through and still picks out the values from when it was loaded, e.g. 1,2,3.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to ensure that my gridview didnt bind twice:

```
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            PopulateGridview();
        }
```